# How do Elasticsearch's "include_in_parent" / "include_in_root" work? Should it show in '_source'?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene, nested

In a simple *Elasticsearch* mapping like this:

```
{
    "personal_document": {
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "include_in_root": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "my_nested": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_root": true,
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.... isn't `"include_in_root": true` supposed to add the field **my_nested.description** to the root document?

> And during a query am I not **supposed to see THAT field into the `_source` field?**

and

> Specifying an `highlight` directive on the field **'my_nested.description'** would automatically retrieve the _included_in_root value_ instead of the *nested field*?

(something like this)
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "description": {},
            "my_nested.description": {}
        }
    }

---

Or do I have some misunderstanding of the [official `nested type` documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping)?
(that is not really clear)

Answer (score 4):

If the include_in_parent or include_in_root options are enabled on the nested documents then  Elasticsearch internally indexes the data with nested fields flattened on the parent document. However, this is just internal for Elasticsearch and you'll never see them in the _source field.

> If the user field is of type object, this document would be indexed
>   **internally** something like this...

as it is refered [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping).

Thus, you continue to perform actions (like the highlights that you mention) by referring to the nested document's fields. The highlight syntax that you refer to should look like this

```
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "my_nested.description": {}
    }
}
```

and not

```
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "description": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about the documentation. Anyway, as you can see in the end of my question, I was trying to get the highlighting referencing the field as `my_nested.description`; but it didn't work. It was acting like that field was not existing. :(

Comment: Thanks Manolis -- I think Kamafeather may have found an alternative, but I'm still interested in the way `include_in_parent` or `include_in_root` work; the difference between them is merely that `include_in_parent` flattens on the parent type, whereas `include_in_root` flattens all the way to the root (the parent's, parent's , parent's.... etc until no parents left) ? This means you couldn't `include_in_grandparent`, right?

Comment: @The Red Pea: From the same documentation, "Nested fields may contain other nested fields. The include_in_parent object refers to the direct parent of the field, while the include_in_root parameter refers only to the topmost “root” object or document.". Thus, you are right about the include_in_parent and include_in_root. There is no option to include_in_grandparent.

Comment: If we use include_in_parent, do we lose the advantage we get using the nested type? meaning, can we not "that each nested object can be queried independently of the others" as mentioned in the nested data type documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard for specifying highlight field:

```
POST /test-1/page/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Lorem ipsum"
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "*" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

If it's a good idea, I don't know. I guess it depends on your application.

This also works with nested documents, btw --- but seems to hickup when doing attachments on nested documents without `include_in_root`